# Nginx multiple subdomains to single url

Tags: nginx

Im new to Nginx never used it before. Got a problem which I can not find solution for.
This question might be asked lots of time but I could not find the answer to it.

How can I configure Nginx for the following scenario 
"my.domain.com/login/" should proxy contents from "login.domain.com" 
"my.domain.com/admin/" should proxy contents from "admin.domain.com" 
"my.domain.com/profile/" should proxy contents from "profile.domain.com"

login.domain.com authenticates users and redirect them to admin.domain.com or profile.domain.com

Will greatly appreciate any help or any reference to the similar solution.

Best,

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 80;
    server_name my.domain.com;
    location /login/ {
        proxy_pass http://login.domain.com/;
    }
    location /admin/ {
        proxy_pass http://admin.domain.com/;
    }
    location /profile/ {
        proxy_pass http://profile.domain.com/;
    }
}
```

It sounds like you'd also have to add a bunch of [`proxy_redirect`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_redirect) directives, like so:

```
location /login/ {
    proxy_pass http://login.domain.com/;
    proxy_redirect http://login.domain.com/ /login/;
    proxy_redirect http://admin.domain.com/ /admin/;
    proxy_redirect http://profile.domain.com/ /profile/;
}
```

Or, maybe use regular expressions, like this:

```
location /login/ {
    proxy_pass http://login.domain.com/;
    proxy_redirect http://([a-z]+).domain.com/ /$1/;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem is that back-end hosts are also hosted on public network, and all the time users get redirected to the actual website like whenever I type my.domain.com/login/ the url in browser I see is login.domain.com. I want want users to see the actual url of the site.

Comment: Oh I missed that, back-end server are on https://  and proxy_redirect off; also don't work. Once I put my.domain.com/login in browser the server response is https://login.domain.com/something/login